# How to get input relative to Xrm.Page.getContext("*any name*") or getAttribute

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am using CRM Online and I want to get DOM element from XRM.Page object using JavaScript. So, how can I get access to input that is relative to control or attribute element got from Xrm.Page.getContext("*any name*") or Xrm.Page.getAttribute("*any name*").

Comment: what do you need exactly? can you make an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting access to the HTML DOM of a form is not supported and cannot be done through the `Xrm.Page` API (which is deprecated b.t.w.). It is not recommend too as Microsoft can decide to modify page rendering without giving notice.

However, you can customize the UI of a form to a high degree by designing your own PCF control. You can find a [Tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/implementing-controls-using-typescript), along with a few [sample components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/use-sample-components).

Guido Preite created a [PCF Gallery](https://pcf.gallery/) with tons of great examples.